# Invoke a web service by using wsimport generation java from Grails Project

Tags: java, web-services, grails, soap, wsdl

I use the wsimport to generate a Web service Client. Such like

*wsimport -extension -keep -p [package] [wsdl file]*

It works well by using it in java project.

But I want to invoke it in a Grails Project.
So I put these generated classes by wsimport into the src/java folder.
And I invoke it in "controllers" of Grails project such as

```
*Holder<String> result = new Holder<String>()
Holder<String> description = new Holder<String>()
RCCWebServiceClientHandler.createSubscription(591, "1234", "1234324543", "453452345", "", 0, "78",4, "", "", result, description)
println(result.value)
println(description.value)*
```

Occur exception is

```
2015-03-19 17:44:13,162 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - WebServiceException occurred when processing request: [GET] /GrailsExample/webservice/index
Method __execute is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name __execute in the wsdl:portType{http://syniverse.com}soap. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Method __execute is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name __execute in the wsdl:portType{http://syniverse.com}soap
    Line | Method
->>  341 | freeze                 in com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     94 | freeze                 in com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl
|    240 | buildRuntimeModel . .  in com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler
|    672 | createSEIPortInfo      in com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate
|    660 | addSEI . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    329 | getPort                in     ''
|    312 | getPort . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    294 | getPort                in     ''
|    119 | getPort . . . . . . .  in javax.xml.ws.Service
|     72 | getSoapServiceImplPort in com.syniverse.sponsordata.ws.client.Soap_Service
|     38 | createSubscription . . in com.syniverse.sponsordata.ws.client.handler.RCCWebServiceClientHandler
|     16 | ws                     in com.syniverse.sponsordata.GroovyTest
|     15 | index . . . . . . . .  in grailsexample.WebserviceController
|    198 | doFilter               in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                    in java.lang.Thread
```

I don't know which method invoke __execute method. And why it works well by using java invoking, but it fails in Grails Project?

---

Update:

1. Refer the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317033/spring-wsdl-no-corresponding-wsdl-operation-with-name](http://[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317033/spring-wsdl-no-corresponding-wsdl-operation-with-name) to know this is about classloader issue from Spring.
2. I used the GGTS IDE, after it add 

   `Dependency:
   compile ":ws-client:1.0"`

   into BuildConfig.groovy

It works. But I still don't know the reason exactly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317033/spring-wsdl-no-corresponding-wsdl-operation-with-name

Answer (score 2):

I have bumped into this problem recently.

With a Grails 2.3.9, the problem seems to be solved if you place this dependency into sour BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    runtime "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.1.7"
```

Probably, the Grails environment has an older JAX-WS runtime by default, so a newer needs to be pulled in.

Also, see Alex Xu-s link (in comments).