# Method __execute is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding sdl operation with name {http://microsoft.com/webservices/}

Tags: java, .net, wsimport

after create java files from wsimport tool,and try to consume web service i got this error

Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method __execute is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {http://microsoft.com/webservices/}__execute in the wsdl:portType{http://microsoft.com/webservices/}UsersServiceSoap
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl.freeze(JavaMethodImpl.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.freeze(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:320) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.(DatabindingImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.microsoft.webservices.UsersService.getUsersServiceSoap(UsersService.java:56) ~[main/:na]
    at com.microsoft.webservices.UsersService$getUsersServiceSoap.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.asal.attendance.AccountService$$EPWLrhGY.$tt__doTest(AccountService.groovy:20) ~[na:na]
    at com.asal.attendance.AccountService$$DPWLrhGY.$tt__doTest(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.asal.attendance.AccountService.$tt__doTest(AccountService.groovy) ~[main/:na]
    at 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:50) ~[springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1459) ~[springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at 
    at

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by adding this plugin to gradle.plugin
  runtime "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.1.7"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142013/invoke-a-web-service-by-using-wsimport-generation-java-from-grails-project